# How has the standardization of the Friulian language made the language easier to learn?

Tags: pronunciation, romance-languages, language-planning

I read that, the standardized version of Friulian was made to make learning it simple. However, did it really make the language simpler? Are there still variations in the pronunciation of letters like C, G and Z in the Friulian language in different dialects?

Comment: What website made that claim?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it separately; don't replace the content of an old one and then flag all the answers and comments for being irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is I can't ask another question

Comment: I have the ability to edit them

Comment: @AkshatGoswami If you're blocked from asking questions, there's probably a reason the system has flagged you. You can ask on Meta about how to change that.

Comment: After 6 months, I can ask

Comment: I believe you can ask questions on [Linguistics.Meta](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/) even with a question block.

Answer (score 1):

Language standardization projects make the language easier to learn by specifying a single version for students to focus on, rather than having learning materials split between several dialects, or trying to cover all the dialect variation in a textbook.

But those dialects, and the different pronunciations that go along with them, still exist and are used. They may die out over time if the standard version is the only one used in schools, but this hasn't happened (yet) in the case of Friulian.

Comment: So is that a good or bad thing?

Comment: @AkshatGoswami Must things be simply good or bad?

Comment: Bear in mind that when talking about language change, the needs or struggles of language learners are of no significance at all, because language learners are almost always an insignificant part of the language's constituency. (This doesn't include children: children are language-learning machines, and essentially no properties of a language have ever been shown to have a significant impact on how readily children learn it. This is less true for writing systems, but these are not part of language, but a technology applied to languages.)

Comment: @ColinFine True, though there are also languages being revitalized where there are a lot of L2 learners and not many L1 speakers.

Comment: @Draconis http://www.geocities.ws/rpontisso/alphabet.html

Comment: Ah. So this is about the writing system, and not about the Friulian language at all!

Comment: @ColinFine not necessarily in cases where a language is in the process of being imposed on another population (e.g. due to conquest or colonialism)

Comment: @Tristan: I can conceive that that could happen. But do you know of an example where the conquerers/colonisers went "If we changed the language in this way our new subjects would be able to learn it more easily"?

Comment: @ColinFine not consciously, but there are plenty of cases where large numbers of L2 learners have resulted in drastically simplified morphology of the entire group's speech a few generations down the road

Comment: @Tristan The most famous being Afrikaans, if I'm recalling correctly.

Comment: @Tristan, : sure, but that is not what the question was about. Nobody decided that Afrikaans should be easier, for the benefit of L2 learners: it just happened.

Comment: @ColinFine sure, but I wasn't addressing my comment to the original question, but to your comment which claimed that "when talking about language change, the needs or struggles of language learners are of no significance at all" - something that cases like Afrikaans show not to be true